# Editing question to correct incorrect terminology

Tags: discussion

Post in question:
[Job offer changed by company after acceptance?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/105186/job-offer-changed-by-company-after-acceptance)

Person asking question uses "right to work" where he really means "employment at will", a common mistake.

Is editing the question to replace "right to work" with "employment at will" the right thing to do?

Comment: After clarifying in comments (as done in the post) if that is the proper phrase then yes.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Can you make that an answer?

Comment: done, made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is editing the question to replace "right to work" with "employment at will" the right thing to do?

**After clarifying in comments (as done in the post) if that is the proper phrase then yes.**

When in doubt it is always OK to ask here on Meta as you did, or on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) about the proper way of handling these sort of things. I understand that you may be thinking this more thoroughly as now with 2k+ rep your edits take effect immediately, so one has to be more careful with them.

About this situation I see no problem with that edit; in fact, there was a [highly voted comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/105186/job-offer-changed-by-company-after-acceptance#comment326091_105186) that pointed out that mistake. When I see comments like this it is an indication that an edit like the one you suggest would help.

The good thing is that edits can be rolled back, edited again, etc., so if by any chance the changes you made were not optimal surely someone else may come to correct that (however, one should not count on this and double check your own edits).

Answer (score 1):

> Is editing the question to replace "right to work" with "employment at
>   will" the right thing to do?

Yes, it's the right thing to do.

Or the "right to work" thing to do. Or the "employment at will" thing to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am careful when doing that sort of edit. Sometimes that mistake is the key to the answer. If that mistaken terminology is the source of their confusion then I would rather address it in the answer.  I would state that the question mentioned X but that Y is the term that would apply. I would then describe both.

In this case if they are in a right-to-work state, but not an at-will state, the change didn't get them an answer to  their question.

The person who asked the question added an additional section that showed confusion over the term, even after the comments and answer. I would have thought that answers should address the confusion, instead of editing the confusion out of the question.